# Is a custom session interface accessed in the same way as the default session object?

Tags: python, session, flask

I want to define another session interface that uses itsdangerous, based on [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/51/).

```
app.session_interface = ItsdangerousSessionInterface()
```

The default session is accessed like a dictionary:

```
session['username'] = request.form['username']
```

Once I assign a new interface, do I use it in the same way as the default session object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flask's session is already using itsdangerous](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.sessions.SecureCookieSessionInterface) as of version [0.10](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/commit/3f82d1b68ea6f5bf2970c2df8ff5cf991439a9bf#diff-2eeaed663bd0d25b7e608891384b7298R95).  That snippet is not needed anymore.   To answer the direct question though: yes, you always use the session like a dictionary.